# Why does it show warning sign on Firestore Reference?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I'm trying to make a reference to a document in Firestore. However, once I enter the path to the document, a warning symbol appears. Is there something I'm missing?

[image: Here is the warning]
[image: Here is where the document lives]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field looks correct. The warning symbol seems to be a visual bug, I witness it too sometimes.